# How can I share application cache between two ASP.NET applications

Tags: asp.net, application-cache

Here's the deal,

I have one website over at utopiapimp.com. The website is used for a popular web based game. Some company internets don't allow the website to be accessed so I opened up another domain at utopiashrimp.com. Same website but a different iss application. Both have same database backends. They also both sit on the same virtual machine.  I put my brand new code on shrimp and solve bugs with that code. I host the solid code on pimp. So I can't just forward the shrimp domain to pimp because I need a test bed.

The problem is that they don't share the same application cache. So my question is, can two websites share the same application cache?  I really need to figure this out. I would rather not create a webservice and or a handler that one website needs to hit to change the cache on the other application. Any help on this would be great!

Thanks before hand.

Answer (score 1):

I think you pretty much said it... application cache.... i think there is a security measure impelemented so that when you cache a variable for an application, other applications are not allowed to access that memory... you may have to use server session or since they use the same backend database, use that instead.

Comment: I am using the application cache because I would rather not hit the database again.

Comment: You might as well be on something. Can server cache be shared?

Comment: server session can be shared... application session can not... "server cache" technichaly is when you use a different network server to store cache items... then there is session state which gets into storing session information inproc.

Comment: If you want to have variables available in multiple applications at the same time its going to take a database call or outproc session.

Answer (score 1):

What you're asking is a little out there, and I don't have an exact response, but you COULD check out [Windows Server AppFabric](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/windowsserver/ee695849.aspx). You could potentially set up the AppFabric cache server on the machine you're currently using to host the applications. Provided your application is relatively well designed, you could simply update your data layer to cache using the AppFabric server.

Comment: FYI [App Fabric is now no longer suported and Microsoft recommend using Redis instead](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/appfabric/2015/04/02/microsoft-appfabric-1-1-for-windows-server-ends-support-422016/)